# $_GET in PHP and &

Tags: javascript

i have a problem. I have made a PHP proxy to get json data from an external server using this code :

```
<?php 
$url = $_GET['url'];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo("<h1>".$url."</h1>");

echo (substr($data,0,-1));

?>
```

But i have to pass this link "http://isohunt.com/js/json.php?ihq=ubuntu&sort=age" and since i have an & in there my php script can't properly evaluate the link. How i solve the issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to encode a URL in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before passing the target URL to the script via the url GET parameter, encode it with `urlencode()` (or an equivalent depending on where the target URL enters the situation).

The encoding will be automatically reversed when you retrieve `$_GET['url']`, leaving you with the original (desired) URL. (Kudos to Quentin for correcting me here).

Hope this helps.

Comment: `$_GET` will decode URLs automatically (that's have the point of it). The problem is that they aren't being encoded in the first place!

Comment: @Quentin Thanks - beer and Stackoverflow don't mix. That's something like 10 edits under belt now :$ ...

Answer (score 1):

use `urlencode` to generate the link, e.g.

```
echo '<a href="http://example.com/my-script.php?url="';
echo url_encode( $url );
echo '">click here</a>';
```

which should output

```
<a href="http://example.com/my-script.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fisohunt.com%2Fjs%2Fjson.php%3Fihq%3Dubuntu%26sort%3Dage">click here</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably when you have characters in your data that have special meaning in URIs (such as `&`) you are failing to encode them (as `%26` for that particular character).

Since you are tagging this *jquery-ajax*: stop constructing your URIs manually. Let jQuery do it:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "myProxy.php",
  data: { 
    url: "http://isohunt.com/js/json.php?ihq=ubuntu&sort=age" 
  },
  success: function(){
    // yada yada
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to URL encode before passing url to the url argument. Use the below mentioned link if you want to be quick.

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/